# Restrict edit in Microsoft access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office

I have a database in microsoft access and in anyone can edit this. What I want is the database should be read-only(view only) by default for all users and if someone wants to edit it they have to authorize themselves first to get an edit access.

There's only a single table in my database and I'm using Microsoft Access 2007.

Comment: Is your base `.mdb` or `.accdb` ?

Comment: the base is .mdb

Answer (score 0):

As your database is `.mdb` you can use user level security described [at support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-or-change-access-2003-user-level-security-in-current-access-versions-0c6a10e7-966f-44f4-864e-5d2ef79439fa).
First steps can be done by build-in wizard [look here](https://www.wikihow.com/Establish-User-Level-Security-in-Microsoft-Access).

Also read about [Oner Access Option](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/with-owneraccess-option-declaration-aa6db1da-934a-4cf9-91a5-d517710db82d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for queries that need to be run with more permissions than current user has.

Comment: But i suggest it is better to use free MS SQL Server Express as storage.

Answer (score 0):

1. build a data entry form and change the data permissions to false (ex: allow edits).  Set form to modal and don't allow a close option
2. when opening the database, open this form
3. remove special keys permissions (File/Options) including the 'shift' key when opening, the 'F11' key, and the shortcut menu (so users can't right click the form, go to close or design view.

You've now pretty much locked down your database.  It would take a developer to break into it.  Be careful that you don't lock YOURSELF out of it.  :)

Now that you've locked down your database, you can pursue the ways in which a user may 'authorize themselves'.  I need to know how you want to approach this.

Comment: When creating a numbered list in markdown, use 1. Instead of 1 - as the list type